# how to hide setup button without disabling the View Setup and Configuration setting on profile

Tags: profile, setup

Is there a way for us to hide the Setup button without disabling the "View Setup and Configuration" setting on the profile .

We need to have this setting enabled because in few of the flows we are using GetRecords on the Profile object (ie to get the profile information for logged in user). Hence by disabling this setting, the flow will not work.

Could you please let me know if there is any other way.

Thanks

Comment: You can do this. You need to disable "View Setup and Configuration" to hide "Setup"

Comment: @NagendraSingh Thank you for responding . A quick question on this . In the flow I mentioned, GetRecords is on the Profile object and the condition requirement is Id EQUALS $User.ProfileId (basically to get the logged in user's profile information). So even in this case, can we move it to sub-flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. You need to disable "View Setup and Configuration" to hide "Setup". You can divide your flow into parts here.

The one which fetches the data from profile, convert that to a subflow, run it with System Admin level access `System Context Without Sharing—Access All Data`  and export the required data and let the other flow run as it is.

Comment: Thank you for responding . A quick question on this . In the flow I mentioned, GetRecords is  on the Profile object and the condition requirement is Id EQUALS $User.ProfileId (basically to get the logged in user's profile information). So even in this case, can we move it to sub-flow?

Comment: If you are just using it to fetch self profile id, you need not even create a subflow, as every user will be able to access their profile even if view setup is disabled.

Comment: Is there a way we can get the name of the profile as well and not just the Profile Id?